# Flexible layout in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I want to build layout with columns which should fit in one div.
Problem is that in internet explorer 9 not shows them properly.
For chrome/firefox I used `display: flex;` and then set `width: n%` so everithing quite easy.

Problems apears when I open in IE9. Columns are shown with no width and height.
I tried [flexie](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) but I cannot make it work:

What I tried:
**HTML:**

```
        <div style="height: 100%">
        <div id="boxwrapinner">
            <div id="box1" ></div>
            <div id="box2"></div>
            <div id="box3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #boxwrapinner {
  display: box;
  box-orient: vertical;
  box-direction : reverse;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#box1 {
box-ordinal-group: 2;

    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2 {
box-ordinal-group: 2;

    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box3 {
box-ordinal-group: 2;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Maybe someone used flexie and can tell me what it requires to work exept just importing `.js` lib file.

Also will apreciate sollution for IE9 how to achieve column layout for divs egzmpl:
[image]

Comment: You have to initialize Flexie for your element. See the Creating a new Flexie Object section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with this a bit and I think the problem was that the DIVs were display: block. I changed it to inline-block and it worked fine

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
#boxwrapinner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box3 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="height: 100%">
        <div id="boxwrapinner">
            <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
            <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
            <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Using this updated CSS it will work even without specifying the height:

```
.box {
    width: 33%;
    display:table-cell;
}

#box1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box3 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: works, only if ` height: 200px;` set in pixels. maybe there is possibilyti to make it work with `height:100%` or another way to grap all space??

Comment: height: 100% doesnt really work unfortunately
P.S. Oh I figured it out, just use `display:table-cell;` for the boxes and you don't even need all the flexbox stuff

Comment: `table-cell` example not working for me in IE9

Comment: Yeah right, I forgot. I added some text inside one of the divs. So if you add some lipsum or something the other DIVs should extend to the height of the largest one. But if you actually use this layout one of the DIVs will probably have enought content to fit the screen so that shouldn't be a problem